# How do I count the associations between each variable and value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, associations

I have a large data frame with 31 Columns (V1:V31) and a large number of rows that have different combinations of V1:V31. The NAs indicate when that variable was not part of the combination. The example below is a subset of my data with just the first 8 variables and first 5 combinations. I have ranked the value of each variable into low/mid/high.

```
   V1  V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8 
1 Low Low High <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 Low Low <NA> High <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
3 Low Low <NA> <NA> High <NA> <NA> <NA> 
4 Low Low <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> High <NA> 
5 Low Low <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> High
```

What Im trying to find are the number of times a variable with one value (low/mid/high) is associated with another variable's value (low/mid/high).

For Example:

How often is V2 low/mid/ high when V1 is **low**?

How often is V2 low/mid/ high when V1 is **mid**?

How often is V2 low/mid/ high when V1 is **high**?

How often is V3 low/mid/ high when V2 is **low**?

And so on.

Expected Results:

```
V1low <- data.frame()

   Low Mid High    
V2 11  3   4 
V3 45  5   34 
V4 3   67  5 
V5 6   45  5 

V1mid<- data.frame()

   Low Mid High    
V2 11  3   4 
V3 45  5   34 
V4 3   67  5 
V5 6   45  5 

V1high<- data.frame()

   Low Mid High    
V2 11  3   4 
V3 45  5   34 
V4 3   67  5 
V5 6   45  5 

V2low<- data.frame()

   Low Mid High    
V3 11  3   4 
V4 45  5   34 
V5 3   67  5 
V6 6   45  5
```

How can I go about this problem?

Edit using @dario 's solution:

```
> results <- table(Pvart2$V1, Pvart2$V2, Pvart2$V3, Pvart2$V4, useNA="always",deparse.level = 2)
> results
, , Pvart2$V3 = High, Pvart2$V4 = High

         Pvart2$V2
Pvart2$V1 High  Low  Med <NA>
     High    0    0    0    0
     Low     0    0    0    0
     Med     0    0    0    0
     <NA>    0    0    0    2
```

At higher dimensions than two the conditions for each dataframe become too high, resulting in too many results. The above example looks for values of V1 and V2 when V3 is high and V4 is high. But that condition is never fulfilled in the 2700 rows of combinations I have. The pairwise aspect also produces a lot of data that I cant look at quickly. Something like the expected results would be more manageable where for every Low V1, it tells me the how many low/mid/high per Variable V1 is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question but I think you can use `table` to do that:

Create a minimal example data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(V1= c("low", "mid", "low", "high", "low"),
                 V2=c("mid", "high", NA, "high", "mid"),
                 V3=c("high", NA, "mid", "mid", "mid"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Use`table` to show the frequencies of the variable-value pairings.

```
table(df$V1, df$V2, useNA="always",deparse.level = 2)
```

We can also pass more than two "dimensions":

```
table(df$V1, df$V2, df$V3, useNA="always",deparse.level = 2)
```

## Edit:

"Manual" frequency table for custom selection using dplyr

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1= c("low", "mid", "low", "high", "low"),
                 V2=c("mid", "high", NA, "high", "mid"),
                 V3=c("mid", NA, "mid", "mid", "mid"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  filter(V1 == "low") %>%
  group_by(V1, V2, V3) %>% 
    summarise(N = n())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This very close. I think you understood what I needed well. It works well for two dimensions but the results using the table function become unusable at a higher dimension. Check my edit

Comment: Ok... still not 100% sure if I understand what you want to do but here is another way (see edit)